# get() returns empty rows in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, get

I am using the function below but it did not return any rows. I tried to do `$query->num_rows()` but it has `null` values. I got the last query using `$this->db->last_query()`, used this in the database and there are results. Am I missing a setup in Code Igniter? Looking forward to your reply.

```
function search($conditions=NULL,$tablename="",$orderby='id', $order='DESC',$limit=1000000,$offset=0)
{
        if($tablename=="")
        {
            $tablename = $this->table;
        }
        if($conditions != NULL)
            $this->db->where($conditions);
        if ( $orderby !== "" and $order !== "")
            $this->db->order_by($orderby, $order);
        $query = $this->db->get($tablename,$limit,$offset=0);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, are you trying to apply $this->query->num_rows() on return value of this function?

Comment: I made a simple function just like below and did not work because of the $query->num_rows() is empty.
function searchTest( $tablename )
{
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get( $tablename );
    echo "COUNT:".$query->num_rows();
    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
      $data = $query->result_array();
    }  
    return $data;
}

Comment: print your last Query- echo $this->db->last_query();

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
if($conditions != NULL)
    $this->db->where($conditions);
if ( $orderby !== "" and $order !== "")
    $this->db->order_by($orderby, $order);
$this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
$query = $this->db->get($tablename);
```

Comment: @Gauta3164, thanks for the reply. I tried it but did not work.

Comment: When I used, $query->num_rows(), it returned empty value.

Answer (score 0):

first you check $tablename is table name or blank

```
function search($conditions=NULL,$tablename="",$orderby='id', $order='DESC',$limit=1000000,$offset=0)
    {
            if($tablename=="")
            {
                $tablename = $this->table;
            }
            if($conditions != NULL)
                $this->db->where($conditions);
            if ( $orderby !== "id" and $order !== "DESC")
                $this->db->order_by($orderby, $order);
            $this->db->limit($limit);
            $this->db->offset ($offset );
            $query = $this->db->get($tablename);
       if($query->num_rows() == 0){
    }
```